# error occuring :ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis . not able execute query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select s.mname,count(distinct s.actorlist) as act 
from p s 
group by s.mname
having count(distinct s.actorlist) = 
                                  (select max(t.act) 
                                  from (
                                        select s1.mname,count(distinct s1.actorlist) as act 
                                        from p s1 
                                        group by s1.mname
                                        ) as t   );
```

error occuring :ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis . not able execute query
Can someone please help me in finding out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, Oracle does not permit `as` for a *table* alias:

```
select s.mname,count(distinct s.actorlist) as act 
from p s 
group by s.mname
having count(distinct s.actorlist) = 
           (select max(t.act) 
            from (select s1.mname, count(distinct s1.actorlist) as act 
                  from p s1 
                  group by s1.mname
                 ) t
           );
```

Do note, however:  I would recommend using window functions for this purpose, rather than nested subqueries.

That would look like:

```
select s.*
from (select s.mname, count(distinct s.actorlist) as act,
             max(count(distinct s.actorlist)) over () as max_act
      from p s 
      group by s.mname
     ) s
where act = max_act;
```

Comment: Hey can you please explain this query

Comment: @parthshah . . . This question is about a syntax error, which I believe is caused by the `as` in the `from` clause.  If you have another question, you should ask it as *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery approach can be simplified as follows:

```
select   mname, count(distinct actorlist) as act 
from     p 
group by mname
having   count(distinct actorlist) = ( select   max( count(distinct actorlist) ) 
                                       from     p 
                                       group by mname
                                     );
```

Notice how the subquery (in the HAVING condition) works: it groups the rows in table `p` by `mname`, then it computes distinct `actorlist` within each group, and then it takes the MAX over all groups (over all `mname`s).

I don't see the benefit of using aliases here, either for tables or for columns. I also see no point in aliasing a table called `p` to `s` - even if you need to fully qualify column names, `p.actorlist` is perfectly fine. By NOT using aliases, you make it clear to a future developer that the subquery is self-contained (it is not correlated to anything in the outer query - it simply computes a number, in a self-contained manner, and it returns that number to the HAVING clause).

In this case, I am not convinced that analytic functions are needed. (Of course, the GROUP BY solution no longer has different levels of nested subqueries, so the reason to consider analytic functions is no longer there.)

You could avoid reading the base table twice by using `dense_rank last` but I would only look at that if performance is poor; otherwise this solution looks pretty clean and easy to explain to anyone and to maintain.